# How can i delete this unresolved reference?

Tags: kotlin, integer

I am looking some help because I've tried to recover some picture with that code for a recycler View:

```
int images [ ] = {
R.drawable.lower_legs; R.drawable.upper_legs; R.drawable.tronc
R.drawable.back; R.drawable.arm_and_shoulder
}
```

but two errors appears : the first one is : unresolved reference with my int, and the second one is Variable expected. I would to recover these pictures with that code in my adapter :

```
holder.muscleImage.setImageResource(images[position])
```

How can I have a right code ? Thanks all !

Comment: That doesn't look like Kotlin to me…  (More like Java, though that would have commas instead of the semicolons, and would need a trailing one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val images = listOf(
    R.drawable.lower_legs, R.drawable.upper_legs, R.drawable.tronc, 
    R.drawable.back, R.drawable.arm_and_shoulder
)
```

I don't want to extrapolate without knowing more context, but it could be argued that the syntax problem you are having is due to not knowing the basic Kotlin syntax.

```
Variable expected
```

Everything has to be, a file, a class, a variable or a function. So when you are assigning `int images [] = ...` you are not doing anything because the correct way to assign a variable is starting the declaration with the reserved word `val`.

```
unresolved reference with my int
```

In Kotlin the type is `Int`, a lower case might be caused by a Java confusion. And the type you need there is `List<Int>`. So by saying `int` you would be trying to assign a single number to a collection of numbers.

As a general recommendation learning new languages just by jumping on a project can be hard, taking an afternoon to read the basic syntax smooths the learning curve.

For Kotlin I would strongly recommend doing the [Koans](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/overview) also [TutorialPoints](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/kotlin/index.htm) is short and straight to the point.